# How to create an Oracle SQL statement in the following case?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, decode

I have an oracle table with three clumns and three data records as shown below

```
ID   FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME       
01     Jason      Martin     
02     Alison     Mathews    
03     Robert     Black
```

I want to select the first name by a given ID.

If the ID exists, i.e., it is a value among 01, 02, and 03, the corresponding FIRST_NAME needs to be displayed;

If the ID does not exist, a * symbol needs to be displayed.
Could you help me creating such an oracle SQL statement?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What if there are more data records or what if I need to select the first name by combinations of multiple fields?

Comment: If you have a different situation to handle, please edit your question showing sample data and desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an outer join, this example using id = 2:

```
select coalesce(FIRST_NAME, '*')
from dual
left join tablename on id = 2
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input. It seems that your solution can be used for a variety of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN ID IN ('01', '02', '03') THEN FIRST_NAME ELSE '*' END
FROM yourTable
```

Note: I assumed, based on your input data, that the `ID` column is `VARCHAR` and not numeric because of the leading zeroes.  If `ID` is numeric, then change the query to this:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN ID IN (1, 2, 3) THEN FIRST_NAME ELSE '*' END
FROM yourTable
```